# How can I get stack traces from restify when I have errors in my code?

Tags: node.js, restify

Let's say I've defined the following restify endpoint:

```
server.get('/test/1', function (req, res, next) {
    undefinedFunctionCall(); // Will cause exception
    return next();
}
```

How can I get a stack trace in my server console which tells me that `undefinedFunctionCall` is undefined? The *client* gets it but not the server.

I've read in [the docs](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#error-handling) that you can listen to the event `InternalServerError` and `InternalError`, but none of the fire when I test. What must I do?

Code:

```
server.on('InternalServerError', function (req, res, err, cb) {
    console.log('INTERNAL ERROR!'); // Never executed
    return cb();
});
```

I'm running Restify 4.0.0 on node 0.10.33 on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, this seems to have changed with version 4.0.0. I'm still on version 0.10 and the stack trace is automatically output to the server console.

However, try this solution that I gleaned from [this post](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/414). I tried it and it works for me.

```
server.on('uncaughtException', function (req, res, err, cb) {
    console.log(err);
    return cb();
});
```

It's not exactly the same as the server dies, but at least you're getting a stack trace.